# Как при наличии заданого значения в столбце удалить все строки со значением другого столбца?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имеется фрейм данных:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': '2019 2019 2019 2020 2020 2020'.split(),
                   'B': 'one two two three two two'.split(),
                   'C': np.arange(6), 'D': np.arange(6) * 2})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если в одной из строк `year` есть значение `one` в колонке `B`, то надо удалить все строки, содержащие в фрейме данных `year: 2019`.

Нужно получить такой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно это сделать?

Comment: пример исходных данных предоставьте в текстовом виде.

Comment: @strawdog добавил в описание

Comment: удалить именно 2019 или год соответствующий `one` ?

Comment: @MaxU нам надо удалить те года, в которых есть "one" в колонке "B". Не конкретно 2019 год, а те года , где есть знаечние "one" в колонке "B". Да, получается соответсвтующий "one"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res = df.groupby("A").filter(lambda x: ~x["B"].eq("one").any())
```

результат:

```
In [53]: res
Out[53]:
      A      B  C   D
3  2020  three  3   6
4  2020    two  4   8
5  2020    two  5  10
```

Comment: А можно без contains это сделать?

Comment: @formanite, можно, но зачем?

Comment: а что означает ~x?

Comment: @formanite, `~series` - оператор инвертирования булевых значений ряда - все `True` становятся `False` и наоборот

Comment: очень долго метод отрабатывает)

Comment: Подскажите , пожалуйста, если не только по "one", но и по другим значениям столбца B как указать несколько значений?

Comment: @formanite, тогда вместо “.eq()” воспользуйтесь “.isin()”

Answer (score 0):

при ваших исходных данных:

```
res = df[df["A"] != (df.loc[df["B"]=="one", "A"].item())]
```

тогда res:

```
      A      B  C   D
3  2020  three  3   6
4  2020    two  4   8
5  2020    two  5  10
```

Comment: результат получается не тот, который указан в вопросе...

Comment: @MaxU я пояснения автора увидел после того, как запостил ответ